# Creating a simple dictionary app on eclipse

Tags: java, android, dictionary, lifecycle

Hi everybody I'm new on android programming and I can say that these are my first basic steps on the way.

I want to create a simple dictionary which has searching behavior. The reason of posting this question is that I want to learn the way. What are the steps of creating such an app. I'm not asking for coding but just some advices on life cycle for creating such kind of app.

Thanks from now on.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do some googling and come back when you've got a specific technical question.

Comment: follow this tutorial here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: You have to use a database. Put 3 tables in it: Words_A, Words_B and AB (to bidirectionally link Word_A and Word_B word indices). That's pretty much of it.

Comment: Create a DataBase- words and Meanings. This can be static or be based on a web service or even a AI module. Once this DB is set up, you will have to provide the user with a search editText control. Next there are some cases you need to address like a  Wrong spelling(If some one is finding a meaning to some word, it is possible that he spells it wrongly),then options like Populate suggestions as the user types and so on.

Comment: @LadyBernkastel actually not because it's not because i just want to learn the basic step rather than those broad and complicated steps.

Comment: @user3564321 thank you very much for link i really need such kind of advices..

Comment: @DerGolem now im trying to understand exactly what you mean i think after reading those links given above i will be able to understand your advice completely. thanks for visiting and writing that advice.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. thank you very much now i see the way clearly at least while learning codes  i will be able to find what the codes do and how they do..

Comment: @user3637702 Go ahead! Feel free to google and you will hit it!

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` is a window that contains the user interface of your application. As there are various states of activity like Running, Paused, Stopped and Killed.

Activity base class contains events that govern the life cycle of an activity.

`onCreate():` Called when the activity is first created
`onStart():` Called when the activity becomes visible to the user
`onResume():` Called when the activity starts interacting with the user
`onPause():` Called when the current activity is being paused and the previous activity is being resumed
`onStop():` Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user
`onDestroy():` Called before the activity is destroyed by the system
`onRestart():` Called when the activity has been stopped and is restarting again

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/648480/Android-Activity-Life-Cycle

Answer (score 0):

I am actually new at this a few months ago. I followed this tutorial : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

You should also try to read about the databases too :) sql lite and such! :) Goodluck friend!